# how to return object from service to component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, return, observable, subscribe

I would like to get results array from atom.service into atom.component. I thought I could bring in results array into atom.component with source codes below (not presented whole codes). But I found I could not access this.atoms in atom.component from source codes below. The results array in atom.service.ts was created successfully. If anyone knows about how to get access to results array in the atom.component, could you give some guide about it?

atom.service.ts

```
getAtoms(private newConcept: string) {
    this.http.get('api/atoms.json')
    .map( (responseData) => {return responseData.json()})
    .subscribe( data => {   
        let results:Array<RAtom> = [];
        for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) { 
            results.push(new RAtom(data.result[i].classType, data.result[i].ui));
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

atom.component.ts

```
atoms: Array<RAtom>;

searchAtoms(newConcept: string) {
    if (newConcept) {
    this.atoms = this.service.getAtoms(newConcept);
    }
}
```

RAtom.ts

```
export class RAtom {
    classType: string;
    ui: string;

    constructor(classType: string, ui:string) {
      this.classType = classType;
      this.ui = ui;
    }
}
```

Comment: Subscribe in the component, not in the service. The Angular 2 docs are full of examples of this.

Comment: First, could I ask how they are different, I roughly understand but could I ask it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I forgot to say, thank you so much for your kind reply!

Answer (score 2):

You can't get back from async execution to sync execution.

Instead of subscribing in `getAtoms()` let the caller subscribe, then he can pass a callback that gets called when the data arrives:

```
getAtoms(private newConcept: string) {
    return this.http.get('api/atoms.json')
    .map( (responseData) => {return responseData.json()})
    //.subscribe( data => {   
    .map( data => {    
        let results:Array<RAtom> = [];
        for (i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) { 
            results.push(new RAtom(data.result[i].classType, data.result[i].ui));
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

```
atoms: Array<RAtom>;

searchAtoms(newConcept: string) {
    if (newConcept) {
      this.service.getAtoms(newConcept)
      .subscribe(result => this.atoms = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally. Glad to hear. Sorry again for being so sloppy.